# Error using make with MASM

Tags: gnu-make, masm

I'm having trouble getting make to work with MASM. I have a single file main.asm in the directory. My makefile looks like this:

```
main : main.obj
    link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE main.obj c:/Irvine/Kernel32.lib 

main.obj: main.asm
    ml /c /coff main.asm
```

The output on the commandline is as follows:

> ml /c /coff main.asm
>
> Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.
>
> Assembling: c:/
>
> MASM : fatal error A1000: cannot open file : c:/
>
> make: *** [main.obj] Error 1

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.